# Send the content of an Array in a text file in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, file-io, numbers, text-files

I'm creating a little program in c# that allows you to send the content of an array of numbers to a text file. But when I open the text file, it only show the last element of the array (10). How can I make sure that he sends all the numbers in the text file and not only the last number.

```
int[] Numbers = { 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
        string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        foreach (var x in Numbers)
        {
            File.WriteAllText(path + @"\" + "numbers.txt", x .ToString () + "\r\n";
        }
```

Comment: Just replace WriteAllText with AppendAllText

Comment: For each loop you are creating a new file and only writing one line.  Open the file only once before the FOR loop and then Close the file after the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `string.Join` and get rid of the `foreach`:

```
 File.WriteAllText(path + @"\numbers.txt", string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Numbers));
```

---

Or you could use the `foreach` loop but change to `AppendAllText` instead of `WriteAllText`:

```
foreach (var x in Numbers)
{
    File.AppendAllText(path + @"\numbers.txt", x.ToString() + "\r\n");
}
```

`WriteAllText` will replace all the text in a file while `AppendAllText` will append to the file.  In your example `WriteAllText` is overwriting the previous value(s) so you only end up with the last value in the file.

Comment: this is the best answer because the i/o operation only happens once